# Maven setup error in Ubuntu

Tags: java, maven, ubuntu

I have a small nanoPC with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS installed and Jenkins, but I've found myself needing to install Maven to use with Jenkins. I have installed Maven, but when I try to check the version using `mvn --version`, I get the following:

[image: mvn --version Terminal output]

I have:

- Set the Java environment variables and tested it with `java -version`.
- Set the Maven environment variables.
- Tried navigating to that location in the terminal and doing `ls`, getting the files list wich includes java.
- Tried executing java and get the list of available commands.

What am I missing here?

Comment: What is `JAVA_HOME` set to?  Is your Java JDK 1.8?

Comment: Install Java correctly, and remove `/home/damian/Documents/jdk*` which isn't the correct JDK for your platform.

Comment: As I'm currently running 14.04 as well, may I suggest webupd8's oracle-java-ppa? I've been using it for a while now and never experienced any problems. Take a look: http://www.webupd8.org/2012/09/install-oracle-java-8-in-ubuntu-via-ppa.html They also provide a package called oracle-java8-set-default which configures system variables correctly.

Comment: Thank you all, now its working. I have installed java using @DoeJohnson solution, but i still had to fix the variables manually.